# In Fluent / Vapor 4, how do I filter a list based on a foreign key?

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor, vapor-fluent

so I have models names `Organization`, `User`, and `App`. Apps and Users both belong to organizations.

```swift
final class Organization: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "organizations"

    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String
    
    @Children(for: \.$organization)
    var users: [User]
}

final class App: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "apps"

    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String

    @Parent(key: "organization_id")
    var organization: Organization
}


final class User: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "users"

    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "email")
    var email: String

    @Field(key: "password_hash")
    var passwordHash: String
    
    @Parent(key: "organization_id")
    var organization: Organization
}
```

Now, basically what I want to do is, **given a user, I want to get all the Apps that belong to that user's organization**.

I can get the user from my auth system, but then all I have is this query:

```swift
let user = try req.auth.require(User.self)
return App.query(on: req.db).filter(\.$organization.id == user.$organization.id).all()
```

This fails with the error message `Operator function '==' requires that 'UUID' conform to 'QueryableProperty'`.

What should I do instead?

Comment: As per the Vapor docs for the filter, the operator expressions accept a field key path on the left hand side and a value on the right. A field key path is nothing but the variable name with a $ symbol.

Please refer: https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/query/#value-filter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to provide the key path to the projected value of a property wrapper you want to filter on, instead of the value itself. So as you discovered it needs to be:

```
.filter(\.$organization.$id == user.$organization.id)
```

The reason why you have to use the property wrapper's projected value instead of just the property itself is because the property wrapper contains the information it needs to perform the query (like the column name) which wouldn't be available with just the property

Answer (score 2):

User `jimmy#2207` from the Vapor discord provided me with this answer:

```swift
let user = try req.auth.require(User.self)
        
// Only show user's orgs' apps, thanks to @jhoughjr
return App.query(on: req.db)
    .filter(\.$organization.$id == user.$organization.id)
    .all()
```

I don't exactly know why it works, but this is the correct combination of backslashes and dollar signs.